# MySQL server tweaks

Tags: ubuntu

My server has...

```
Processor(s)      Dual (2x) Intel Xeon 2GHz 5130 Dual Core 64-Bit Processors - 4MB Cache, 1333MHz FSB
Memory          4GB RAM (4x 1GB PC2-5300) - 8 slots on motherboard
Hard Drive(s)    Four (4) Hitachi 500GB 7200RPM SATA Hard Drives
```

I'm wondering if I should change any memory settings for MySQL.  Currently there is no limit on MySQL connections... the settings are all default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend you check out http://www.day32.com/MySQL/ and http://blog.mysqltuner.com/ who both provide scripts that can help you analyze and perform some basic tweaking to MySQL.

Comment: +1 The default configuration is never quite right for production and mysqltuner is a great resource.